# Get results back from an Android activity that hosts a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm just learning Android development. Currently I'm practicing the communication between activities and fragments and handle their results. I have a question about the following situation: ActivityA starts ActivityB that hosts FragmentB and ActivityA wants to get the results back. I often see the following code:

```
// ActivityA start ActivityB code
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra(FragmentB.EDIT_TEXT, textView.getText());
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);

// FragmentB (hosted by ActivityB) set result code
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra(EDIT_TEXT, value);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
finish();

// ActivityA handle result code
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    CharSequence val = data.getCharSequenceExtra(FragmentB.EDIT_TEXT);
    textView.setText(val);
  }
}
```

This does not look like a clean approach to me, because ActivityA has to know the implementation detail of ActivityB - that is hosts FragmentB. A cleaner approach I came up is putting an interface bewteen FragmentB and ActivityB: ActivityB implements an interface of FragmentB. The method of this interface gets called by FragmentB when ActivityB can finish itself (I try to make the code as short as possible :-):

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

  private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

  private TextView textView;

  private void startEditActivity() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
    i.putExtra(ActivityB.EDIT_TEXT, textView.getText());
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      CharSequence val = data.getCharSequenceExtra(ActivityB.EDIT_TEXT);
      textView.setText(val);
    }
  }

}

public class ActivityB extends Activity
  implements FragmentB.OnEditSetListener
{
  public final static String EDIT_TEXT = "nl.michiel.testapp.editTextActivity";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    CharSequence val = getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(EDIT_TEXT);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, FragmentB.newInstance(val))
      .commit();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onEditSet(CharSequence value) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(EDIT_TEXT, value);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
  }

}

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

  public final static String EDIT_TEXT = "nl.michiel.testapp.editTextFragment";

  private CharSequence value;
  private EditText editText;
  private OnEditSetListener editSetListener;

  public interface OnEditSetListener {
    public void onEditSet(CharSequence val);
  }

  public static FragmentB newInstance(CharSequence value) {
    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequence(EDIT_TEXT, value);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof OnEditSetListener) {
      editSetListener = (OnEditSetListener)activity;
    } else {
      throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
        + " must implement OnEditSetListener");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    value = getArguments().getCharSequence(EDIT_TEXT);
  }

  // Called when edit has finished, for example after a button click
  private void editFinished() {
    editSetListener.onEditSet(editText.getText());
  }

}
```

So is this a good solution, or are there some common ways to handle these situations?